# Finding an appropriate distance/divergence/similarity measure in a real 2D phase space

Tags: distributions, distance, similarities, bivariate

At first, I have to excuse my sloppy terminology, as I am pretty new to the whole topic.

Imagine a real twodimensional phase space representing climate-related properties. I have a set of N variables from an arbitrary bivariate distribution representing this properties within region A in, lets say the 1950s. And I have another set of N variables from another arbitrary distribution (which should be, however, quite similar to the first one) representing this properties within the same region in, lets say the 1990s.

What I want to investigate is similarity or divergence. And also if a third set of points which I have from region B, is more similar to region A in the 1990s then region A is to itself in the 1950s. I hope you get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem belongs to [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification), and [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning).

On your problem in particular. Since it has only two dimensions, it would be a good idea to do a scatter plot of your data (2D plot, with your 2dim), but use different colours for different sets and go from there.